# A union of topologies is a topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking at a proof that the statement 'A union of topologies is a topology' is false. It goes as follows:

> False. For instance, if $T = T_1 \cup T_2$ and $U_1 \in T_1$, but not $T_2$, while $U_1 \in T_2$, but not $T_1$, then $U_1, U_2 \in T$ , but it does not follow that $U_1 ∩ U_2 \in T$.

Surely if $U_1 \in T_1$, but not $T_2$, while $U_1 \in T_2$, but not $T_1$, then their intersection is empty, and the empty set is in the topology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $X=\{a,b,c\}$, let $\tau_{1}=\{X,\emptyset,\{a,b\}\}$, $\tau_{2}=\{X,\emptyset,\{b,c\}\}$ but $\{a,b\}\cap\{b,c\}=\{b\}\notin\tau_{1}\cup\tau_{2}$.

Comment: That's made it much clearer! Where does my argument go wrong then?

Comment: To show it's false you need only exhibit a single concrete counterexample (as this answerer did).

Comment: Think of this: $U_{1}\subseteq X$ and $U_{2}\subseteq Y$ but $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, then $U_{1}\cap U_{2}=\emptyset$, but now you have $U_{1}\in\tau_{1}$, $\in$ and $\subseteq$ are different issue.